# How to get parameters in an HTML page passed from a snippet with Lift framework

Tags: html, web-applications, lift

I want to develop a Lift web app, I've an index page that has in here body:

```
<div id="main" class="lift:surround?with=default&at=content">
  <div> App </div> 
  <div>
    <form method="post" class="lift:DumbForm">
       <table>
            <tr><td> Email:</td> <td><input name="email" type="text"></td></tr>
            <tr><td> Password:</td> <td><input name="pwd" type="password"></td></tr>
            <tr><td> Name:</td> <td><input name="name" type="text"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Sign in"></td> <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
  </div> 
</div>
```

With the corresponding snippet (file "DumbForm.scala"):

```
package code
package snippet

import net.liftweb._
import http._
import scala.xml.NodeSeq

/**
 * A snippet that grabs the query parameters
 * from the form POST and processes them
 */
object DumbForm {
  def render(in: NodeSeq): NodeSeq = {  
    // use a Scala for-comprehension to evaluate each parameter
    for {
      r <- S.request if r.post_? // make sure it's a post
      name <- S.param("name") // get the name field
    } {
      S.notice("Nom: "+name)
      S.redirectTo("/hello")
    }

    // pass through the HTML if we don't get a post and
    // all the parameters
    in
  }
}
```

I want to pass the attribute "name" from this snippet to another view, HTML page, ("hello.html") that would get and display this name.

**But I don't know how to pass the "name" parameter from the snippet to the view (hello.html), and how to get this parameter in the view?!**

For this moment, my hello.html has:

```
<body>
<p> Hello ... (you must display the name!)</p>
</body>
```

Comment: I want to know how to set a variable with request parameters (in the snippet) and to get this parameter in the view (HTML)?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you are looking to do, you would just point the form directly at where ever `hello.html` is mounted. I am assuming it is `hello` in the same path.

**dumbform.html**

```
<div id="main" class="lift:surround?with=default&at=content">
  <div> App </div> 
  <div>
    <form method="post" action="hello">
       <table>
            <tr><td> Email:</td> <td><input name="email" type="text"></td></tr>
            <tr><td> Password:</td> <td><input name="pwd" type="password"></td></tr>
            <tr><td> Name:</td> <td><input name="name" type="text"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Sign in"></td> <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
  </div> 
</div>
```

**hello.html**

```
<div data-lift="ShowHelloSnippet">
  <p>Hello <span name="paramname"></span></p>
</div>
```

**Snippet**

```
class ShowHelloSnippet {
  def render = {
    "@paramname" #> S.param("name")
  }
}
```

---

The more Lift way to do it thought, would be to use Lift's [SHtml form elements](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.0/framework/scaladocs/net/liftweb/http/SHtml%24object.html):

**dumbform.html**

```
<div id="main" class="lift:surround?with=default&at=content">
  <div> App </div> 
  <div>
    <form method="post" data-lift="FormHandlerSnippet">
       <table>
            <tr><td> Email:</td> <td><input name="email" type="text"></td></tr>
            <tr><td> Password:</td> <td><input name="pwd" type="password"></td></tr>
            <tr><td> Name:</td> <td><input name="name" type="text"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input id="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Sign in"></td> <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Snippet

```
class MyFormResponse(
    var email:String="", 
    var password:String="", 
    var name:String ="")

class FormHandlerSnippet {

  def render = {
     val responseForm = new MyFormResponse()
     "@email" #> SHtml.text("", (valueSupplied) => {
        responseForm.email = valueSupplied
     }) &
     "@pwd" #> SHtml.password("", (valueSupplied) => {
        responseForm.password = valueSupplied
     }) &
     "@name" #> SHtml.text("", (valueSupplied) => {
        responseForm.name = valueSupplied
     }) &
     "#submitbutton" #> SHtml.submit("Sign In", () => {
        S.redirectTo("/hello", () => ShowHelloSnippet.myVals(Full(responseForm)))
     })
  }
}
```

**hello.html**

```
<div data-lift="ShowHelloSnippet">
  <p>Hello <span name="paramname"></span></p>
</div>
```

**Snippet**

```
object ShowHelloSnippet {
  object myVals extends RequestVar[Box[MyFormResponse]](Empty)
}

class ShowHelloSnippet {
  def render = "*" #> {
    ShowHelloSnippet.myVals.get.map { r =>
      "@paramname" #> r.name
    }
  }
}
```

This will have the form set values on a object, then do a stateful redirect which sets the values in the `ShowHelloSnippet` for you to use after the page has been redirected. As an alternate to both, you could use Ajax to simply display the values on the same page.

Comment: I don't get the name?!
I've in HTML:
<body>
<div data-lift="DumbForm">
  <p>Hello <span name="paramname"></span></p>
</div>
</body>
and the snippet:
object DumbForm {
  def render(in: NodeSeq): NodeSeq = {
    for {
      r <- S.request if r.post_?
      name <- S.param("name")
    } {
      S.notice("Nom: "+name)
      "@paramname" #> name
      S.redirectTo("/hello")
    }
    in
  }

Comment: the render method has:
  def render(in: NodeSeq): NodeSeq = {
    for {
      r <- S.request if r.post_?
      name <- S.param("name")
    } {
      S.notice("Nom: "+name)
      "@paramname" #> name
      S.redirectTo("/hello")
    }
    in
  }

Comment: You can't set the variable and redirect unless the variable is is session scoped. I will update my answer to show one way you can do what I think you are trying to do.

Comment: I updated the answer with more of what I think you are trying to do. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: On snippet, after doing: import net.liftweb.common.Full
I've got an error ("code.snippet.ShowHelloSnippet") on this line: S.redirectTo("/hello", ShowHelloSnippet.myVals(Full(responseForm)))
What could I do, please?!

Comment: Sorry, the second param to Redirect should have been a function, I updated the code with `() =>` and that should hopefully work.

Comment: I just saw that there is a problem, in fact the field "PASSWORD" displays the password in clear text (instead in asterisk)?!

Comment: I swapped out the text for a password, if you look at http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.0/framework/scaladocs/net/liftweb/http/SHtml%24object.html you can see all of the input types available

Comment: @jcern i would like to know what is the difference between lift: and data-lift: in the view. can u please explain?